# Keep UIScrollView scrolled to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I need somehow to keep scrollview always scrolled to bottom while its height decreases.

It's hard to solve while bounds change animated. Is there some "gravity"-property for purpose like that?

Comment: height decreases of what ? content size or view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this behaviour by using a non-animated version of `setContentOffset`  within the same animation block you use for resizing the `UIScrollView` — in this case both changes will be animated simultaneously. Something like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

    let delta: CGFloat = 100

    /// Change UIScrollView's height with some delta value, for instance:
    self.scrollView.frame.size.height -= delta

    /// Update content offset with the same delta value:
    self.scrollView.contentOffset.y += delta
})
```

Comment: Your answer is correct even for multiple concurrent animations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setContentOffset:animated:` to scroll to the bottom every time you shrink the `UIScrollView`'s frame.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work since height changes animated.

Answer (score -1):

You are decreasing the height of scrollview with animation. You can use `setContentOffset:animated:` in the animation completion block. It will keep the scrollview always scrolled to bottom.

Comment: If you do that in the animation completion block, the content offset will be updated only when the animation finishes, e.g. there will be a "jump" of the scroll view content when the view finishes the resizing animation.